# Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or missing. (0x80070570)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation

My computer started failing to boot this morning, so I tried to reinstall Windows 10. Every time I try to install Windows, I get this error message during installation:

> Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or missing. Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart the installation. Error code: 0x80070570

This happens after deleting all partitions on my drive and reformatting it.

What could be wrong, and how do I go about getting my computer working again?

Google hasn't given any working solutions. Some of the previous error messages yielded results about SSD failure. Seems logical, but `chkdsk` says my SSD is fine, and I can read and write to it. Perhaps also relevant is when I tried to reset my PC from the Windows recovery options, it said my drive was "locked". Nothing in the recovery options did anything helpful, except the command prompt.

Comment: Optical drive? Sounds like a bad ISO or incomplete file list.

Comment: @Yorik I've tried using two different Windows 10 OEM DVDs. Both give this error.

Comment: @KendallFrey - Download the current 1607 ISO from Microsoft and make a new bootable disk from it.  If you are using the wrong version ISO on your installation ( Version 1511 instead of Version 1607 ) you would get this error.

Comment: Do you know _why_ your computer failed to boot in the first place? You ran a CHKDSK on the file-system, but did you also check the drive's SMART status for failures?  Also, you say you "deleting all partitions on my drive and reformatting it." was that before you tried to install Windows?  If you just remove all partitions (leaving the whole disk unallocated) and then let the Windows installer create partitions as needed, does it behave any differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much all speculation, but this is what seemed to be the case.

One of my RAM sticks is faulty (Windows Memory Diagnostics has since confirmed this). After removing it, I had no more trouble installing and using Windows. It appears this may have been the cause of the installation failure.

As for the original problem, my suspicions lie with a crash during a Windows update that rendered the disk unbootable.

Unfortunately I don't have any real evidence of what was happening, aside from the memory diagnostic result.