# Windows 10 Installation - Missing required files and Blue Screens (0x80070570)

Tags: windows-10, memory, bsod, windows-installation, windows-10-v1703

**Issue:**

I am trying to fresh install Windows 10 to my fully unallocated Samsung 950 NVMe drive, with every attempt at around 9-10% it either errors out with

`Error code: 0x80070570 saying Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or missing. Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart the installation.`

Sometimes shortly after it will blue screen with varying different issues, usually related to drivers or memory.

**Troubleshooting:**

After hours of research on Google with little to no finds specific to my case (of course not until after the fact), I ended up going piece by piece.

I disconnected every piece of I/O, my GTX 1060, my storage drives, reseated my DDR4 sticks, except for my mouse/keyboard dongle, a DVI cable, and the bootable flash drive. No changes. I tried multiple different flash drives with different ISOs and different programs for creating them (Rufus, Microsoft's MediaCreationTool, manually). I tried using other devices and platforms to write to the bootable flash drive. I tried a live session of Ubuntu 16.04 and everything was fine, I installed Ubuntu and everything still worked. I tried resetting everything in my BIOS back to default (ASUS Z170 chipset), removing any overclocking or alterations. I tried Windows Home versus Pro and made more progress than ever but still ended up erroring out around 60 to 70%, and then continuing the same pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1143790/windows-cannot-install-required-files-the-file-may-be-corrupt-or-missing-0x80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing one of the two DDR4 DIMMs from my motherboard and the installation was able to complete without any issues.

**Update:**
Once the install was done I ran Windows Memory Diagnostics and it came back clean with no errors. I removed that DIMM I had just successfully used, replaced it with the other one, using the same DIMM slot, booted up, ran Windows Memory Diagnostics and it failed. Doing an Express RMA with Corsair.